# Reordering table row SQLite UITableView

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I am trying to order UITableView rows. I already implemented necessary methods and it works on my mutable array. However I don't know how can I apply this changes to my database.

My database has favs column 
CREATE TABLE `favs` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `w_name`    TEXT
);

I was using "insert or replace into favs (w_name) values ('%@%');" statement to insert new word to favs database. How can I change the id of two records so that I can list the favs values by order of id so that they will be sorted. For example I want to change my table from this

id|w_name

1|apple

2|banana

3|orange

to

id|w_name

1|apple

3|banana

2|orange

I can change the id if the key is not primary by using
UPDATE favs SET id = (CASE id WHEN 2 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END)
WHERE id IN (2, 3);

If I do like this I need to calculate id by myself each time I insert the record. So, how can re-order ids so that my changes in UITableView is reflected into database.

Answer (score 0):

In all case, if you want to reorder you TableView, you've to reorder the array that feed the TableView. 
You can execute the query again. 
Or use that

```
yourArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(TYPE *p1, TYPE *p2){
        return [p1 compare:p2];  
    }];
```

and finish with `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I have no problem about reordering my array which is read from SQLite database. My problem is how can I save changed order into database.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. 
Then, I think you can't. What you want to change is the physical order of the records, then, except if you delete all these records to re-create them, I think you can't. (programmatically ofc)

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your table and call it sort. There you will put the index of each record in your array `[array indexOfObject:object]`. Every time you want to save the order of your array you can update the sort column of each record e.g. 
`const char *sql = "UPDATE favs SET sort = ? WHERE id = ?";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql , -1, &updateStatment, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStatment, 1, [array indexOfObject:object]); sqlite3_bind_int(updateStatment, 2, [object id]);`